# Visual Studio 2012 cannot step into MS source code for System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, linq-to-sql

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Update 4. All the information I can find on this topic seems to apply to Visual Studio 2010.

I have downloaded and set up microsoft symbols and source files:
[image: Symbol File Settings]

I have turned on .NET Framework source stepping and source server support:
[image: General debug settings]

But I still cannot step into source code for System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges.

In the Modules debug window, I can see that it loaded symbols for System.Data.Linq:

> System.Data.Linq.dll  C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\bmarty\Documents\RefSrc\Symbols\Cache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\System.Data.Linq.pdb\ba948c2465de4a1db9d494407920bd141\System.Data.Linq.pdb   11  4.0.30319.18060 7/22/2013 10:35 PM  61AE0000-61D47000   [6176] LinqUpdateTest.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)

But in the debug output, I see:

> Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges'

It wouldn't be because my source is VB.NET and MS source is C# would it?

Comment: @dmarlow Unfortunately I can't remember if I found a work-around for this. I think in the end I just browsed to where I knew the source code was and looked at it without running it.